# Can attackers defeat iOS keychain and data-protection encryption?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, security, sandbox

I am developing an iOS app that it has to store username and password and other sensitive data. I am considering using NSUserDefaults or keychain storage. 
Are there other more secure method to keep attackers from defeating iOS keychain or such data protection?

Comment: There's no such a thing as 100% secure storage. NSUserDefaults is the next worst to the raw txt file as it can be easily read. So we have only the keychain left, if you are interested at 3rd party solutions someone might give good suggestions, please reflect your 3rd parties attitude in the question.

Comment: I'm really surprised! How someone can read data from `NSUserDefaults` as all app have its own `Sandbox area` which would only access by application it self only. I'm really unaware of this, I'm gonna make this question favorite, have you any link / article that show something like this kind of attack?

Comment: Just because it's in a sandbox doesn't mean that it's not easily readable from the filesystem using SSH.

Comment: The MAC application "iExplorer", downloadable from http://www.macroplant.com/, will read or write any file in the sandbox of any app on the device. This is NOT the same app as iExplorer in the Apple app store. Using this app it's easy to read a file, change it, then write it back to the device. It might be true that an app on the device can't read files in another app's sandbox, provided that the device is not jailbroken. But if it's jailbroken anything can read anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a good read-up on this whole security topic [here](http://www.wildsau.net/post/2011/02/08/iOS-4-Data-protection-hardware-encryption-and-other-insight.aspx), it's an older article but anyway. I personally think that the whole security concept on apples iOS platform together with hardware encryption on iOS devices is really good. Android and Android devices are problematic as we all know.

But adding additional security measures, by encrypting your data additionally, is not a bad idea anyway!