# Keychain storage

Tags: ios, keychain

I am developing an application and  using AES256 encryption to store data in keychain.I am using KeychainItemWrapper class provided by apple and storing my data for key kSecAttService.
Will hackers be able to hack data stored in keychain even if I have encrypted and stored?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have to ask yourself is the data you are storing valuable enough to be hacked? I'm sure if it is, then yes, if someone really wants it bad enough, they can grab your data - especially if you are using a wrapper provided by Apple.

Comment: use this like , it may help u.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13248496/can-attackers-defeat-ios-keychain-and-data-protection-encryption